# Python Skript to Read/Write Google Fit Data via REST API

Tags: python, google-fit, google-fit-api, applehealth, google-fitness-api

I recently switch from an iOS Phone to Android. Now I have the problem that all my Apple Health data is not available on my new phone, because Google Fit only imports the 3 last days and all my history.
I exported my Apple Health data to and transformed it into a pandas dataframe.

Now I need to write them to google fit, but unfortunately I have no experience with API's.
I already did some research and found an example here to get goolge authorisation:
requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/google.html

I tried to adjust it to the googlefit api.

```
# Import Google credentials from *.json file
file_name = 'MY_CREDENTIALS.json'
file = open(file_name) 
data = json.load(file)
data_keys = list(data.keys())
client_data = data[data_keys[0]]

client_id = client_data['client_id']
project_id = client_data['project_id']
auth_uri = client_data['auth_uri']
token_uri = client_data['token_uri']
auth_provider_x509_cert_url = client_data['auth_provider_x509_cert_url']
client_secret = client_data['client_secret']
redirect_uris = client_data['redirect_uris']
javascript_origins = client_data['javascript_origins']

# OAuth endpoints given in the Google API documentation
authorization_base_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
token_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
scope = ["openid",
         "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness"]

google = OAuth2Session(client_id,
                       scope = scope,
                       redirect_uri = redirect_uris)

# Redirect user to Google for authorization
authorization_url, state = google.authorization_url(authorization_base_url,
                                                    access_type = "offline", # offline for refresh token
                                                    prompt = "select_account") # force to always make user click authorize

print('Please go here and authorize:', authorization_url)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here: ')

# Fetch the access token
google.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret = client_secret, authorization_response = redirect_response)

# Fetch a protected resource, i.e. user profile
# r = google.get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo')
# r = google.get('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read')
r = google.get('https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources/derived:com.google.step_count.delt')
r = google.get('https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/userId/dataSources')
print(r.content)
```

When I try to execute I get the following error message:

> You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.
>
> You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.
> Weitere Informationen zu diesem Fehler
> Wenn Sie Entwickler von writeHealthData sind, finden Sie in den Fehlerdetails weitere Informationen.
> Fehler 400: invalid_request

Does anyone can help me with the authorisation?
Does anyone has experience with writing data to google fit via REST API?

Thank you in advance.

Greetz Simon

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Google services and APIs, you need the oAuth consent screen to access data types, especially for restricted scopes. Therefore, without definite approval from the user, they will be prompted with the error you mentioned.